# Evaluate a PHP file with the command line

Tags: php, eclipse, web-applications, cordova

I am turning my PHP/MySQL/jQuery Mobile/Javascript webapp into a app thanks to Phonegap. I want to get rid of all PHP code (except while exchanging data with the server) to feed Phonegap with HTML pages. Data-wise, this is not a problem because views and data accesses were properly separated.

My problem is that I used PHP to apply the DRY principle (any HTML pattern that was repeated was rendered with a PHP function call). Since I will be working on both the webapp and the iPhone app, I need to be able to easily export changes to the page into the Phonegap project.

So I am looking for a way to export the pages of my webapp using some command line function in Eclipse. Ideally I would add builders like this to Eclipse:

```
php -F htdocs/index.php > phonegapdirectory/index.html
```

I am obviously missing something because nothing is output. The `php` command is waiting for direct input and I need to type in `exit` for the result to be output correctly.

Any idea on how to make it right?
Is there any other good practice exporting PHP to HTML to Phonegap?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: "It does not work" - great explanation of your problem, I'm contacting Charles Xavier to help me figure out what "does not work" means for you.

Comment: Haha, does not work means it does not output anything and stalls. What I am looking for is a way to output (in a file or in the standard output) the evaluation of the php file. "does not work" means does not do what I want to do.

Comment: to be more specific, it does not stall but waits for direct input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use -F? Are you planning on passing input into the php files?

You could just use

```
php htdocs/index.php > phonegapdirectory/index.html
```

Comment: You are so right! I used `-F` because I read the manual to try to figure out what to do. I did not know I could use `php` without it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Not the additional 2... File channel

```
php -F htdocs/index.php 2> phonegapdirectory/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks, that might help but I am blocked even before that because the `php` command line does not finish and waits for me to type in something like `\n` twice.